# How can I grant specific administrative privileges without granting view/modify all data?

Tags: permissions, user, user-management, userrecordaccess

How can I restrict a user to do only the following activities?

- User maintenance - Create Users, Deactivate Users, Change Permissions, Change Role in hierarchy, Update Name, Federation Id, and other user attributes
- Add Help Text
- Create Fields, modify field attributes, remove from page layouts, modify page layouts, update pick-lists
- Create email template, update email template

The user should not have the ability to view/modify all data.

Comment: So you want this user not to be able to modify the data like Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities, Cases, etc?

Comment: Yes. The user should be able to do only those above mentioned activities

Answer (score 3):

- To [create / modify Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=adding_new_users.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.18), grant **Manage Internal Users** permission
- To [create fields / modify help text](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=adding_fields.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.18) and [page layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=accessing_layout_standard.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.18), grant **Customize Application**
  permission
- To [create / modify email templates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_html_email_templates.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.18), grant **Edit HTML
  Templates** and **Manage Public Templates** permissions
- To [create / modify profile and permission set permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_object_perms_edit.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.18), grant **Manage Profiles and Permission Sets** permission

Please note that granting **Customize Application** permission will automatically grant [additional permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194001&type=1&language=en_US), however this permission is required in order to make the types of changes you described.

See also [More Specific Permissions for Managing Users](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_manage_users_dist_perms.htm) for more specific User management permissions that are available.

The permissions I described above can be granted [using either Profiles or Permission Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=permissions_about_users_access.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.18).